# Sending logs every 2 hours using logstash-forwarder without using cronjob

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, logstash-configuration

Is there a way I can send data using the logstash-forwarder every 2 hours or more without using a cronjob script to start and stop the forwarder every time I want to send the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have LSF monitor logfile2.txt.  Every two hours, append the real contents from logfile1.txt onto logfile2.txt, which LSF will then process for you.

(Note that you didn't say that we couldn't use cron at all, just that you didn't want to start/stop LSF with it).

Comment: That was smart! ;)
And what if I use cron to start and stop the LSF? I have been unable to find the proper command to stop LSF using cron.

Comment: My LSF installed with an init script, so "/etc/init.d/logstash-forwarder stop" works for me.

Comment: Just another doubt if you will, while starting logstash forwarder with

`sudo service logstash-forwarder start`

 how can I specify the configuration file?

Comment: After starting the LSF with the above command, if I check the status it returns that LSF isn't running. I'm assuming that I need to specify a config file. I have tried `sudo service logstash-forwarder -config /etc/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.conf start` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: With an init script, the full command is build up in the script, so to specify a different config location, you'd have to see how the init script is passing that into to LSF and edit the init script as needed.

Comment: Turns out I just have to put the configuration file in `/etc/` without any sub-folders and it works. Thanks for the help! :)